# Kafka broker impact with large number of consumer groups in parallel

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Consider I am having a three node kafka cluster in which there are 1000 topics with single partition. Each topic will be consumed by multiple consumer groups, say 100 in parallel. Therefore totally there can be 1000*100 consumer groups consuming from kafka in parallel.

My concern is whether this would have any performance impact in kafka cluster on a larger scale ?

Also, my model will be starting consumer for each user request and will fetch single data from queue and consumer will be closed on request end. For the next request from same user, consumer will be started for same group again and it will be closed. This will be repeated for all the users.

Whether creating and tearing down consumer in such a fashion is a proper one? If not, is there any other proper way to handle this use case?

Comment: Are you having a topic per user?

Comment: No, a single topic for 100 users, and the kafka version is 0.10.0.1

Comment: I think creating a consumer pool and reusing them would be very efficient than creating and tearing down the consumer threads. But I don't understand why you want to divide a users across multiple topics.

Answer (score 0):

For very high concurrent use cases, consider something like [Parallel Consumer](https://github.com/confluentinc/parallel-consumer) (PC) to sub divide the single partition.

However, it's recommended to have at least 3 partitions and have at least three consumers running in a group, to utilise high availability. You can again use PC to process all these partitions, sub divided by key, in parallel.

PC directly solves for this, by sub partitioning the input partitions by key and processing each key in parallel.
It also tracks per record acknowledgement. Check out [Parallel Consumer on GitHub](https://github.com/confluentinc/parallel-consumer) (it's open source BTW, and I'm the author).